# excel sheet copy to another excel in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I want to copy one excel sheet to another excelsheet in new excelbook using asp.net and sqlserver 2005

please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    string src = @"Book1.xlsx";
    string dst = @"Book2.xlsx";

    object missing = Missing.Value;

    ApplicationClass app = new ApplicationClass();
    WorkbookClass wb1 = (WorkbookClass) app.Workbooks.Open(src, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,missing);
    WorkbookClass wb2 = (WorkbookClass)app.Workbooks.Open(dst, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);

    Worksheet sheet1 = (Worksheet) wb1.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
    Worksheet sheet2 = (Worksheet)wb2.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
    try
    {
        sheet1.Copy(sheet2,missing );
    }catch (Exception ex){
        //
    }
    finally{
        app.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: Hi,                                                             Thanks for your reply.                                            it's working good. i want get binary value of that sheet2.         Can you please explain me.                                                            Thanks & regards,                                            Dhanraj.S

Comment: Do you want to serialize the excel sheet into a stream object? Check out - http://weblogs.asp.net/mecitatmaca/archive/2008/11/02/office-integration-4-serializing-and-de-serializing-excel-spreadsheet-by-using-excelpackage.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague and I'm not sure why you mention SQL Server, but here are some basic suggestions:

You could use [Excel Automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084) but this is normally not recommended on a server, which I assume you're talking about since you mention ASP.Net.

Another option might be OLEDB as described in this code project article: [Reading and Writing Excel using OLEDB](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/excel_using_oledb.aspx)
However, this might not be suitable unless the data is in a tabular format.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Excel 2007 or newer, the file format is actually just a zipped bunch of XML files. There is an SDK available for manipulating Office files, which may be what you're after. This way means no need for Excel, ugly automation etc as it's simply editing  the XML using an open format.

The developer home page is here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee358824.aspx - there's downloads, samples, videos etc there which will hopefully be of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.net and SQL Server 2005 are not really relevant here, as neither of them have anything to do with Excel (unless you are storing your spreadsheets in SQL Server I suppose).

You can access Excel from managed code using the automation client.  You can do this from any managed code (assuming relevant libraries are installed).

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084

This provides an object model for Excel, Worksheets, Cells etc that you can manipulate in code.